# Need for proper air filter for bioreactor?

Tags: microbiology

I am going to build a simple bioreactor for microalgae growth.

I already have fluid filters pore size: 0.2um, diameter: 25mm
https://nl.vwr.com/app/catalog/Product?article_number=514-4039

I wonder if I can use them for air filtration to avoid the bacteria when pumping in the air.
Or do I necessarily need air filters?

Comment: What are your end goals?  These determine your sterility requirements.  Generally if you are aiming for mass protein production you want to filter air both in and out of the reactor.  Normal hippa filters should be sufficient.  I've not known of any liquid filters that could do double duty as air filters, but that doesn't mean it won't work.

Comment: The goal is to maintain and growth the microalgae without getting infected with the bacteria (They would stop the culture from growing) and I will get some samples from bioreactor, occasionally, for imaging. I also think there should be filters both for air in and out. But don't know what would be a sufficient filter (lower price is better of course) for this purpose. It seems that pore size and filtration area are important parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Well then you need to get a filter specific for air filtering.  I recommend Polytetrafluorethylene PTFE membrane filter.  Now the only issues are size and "how sterile."

There are a lot of vendors out there that supply these.  If your institution has an agreement with VWR, they certainly have them.  If not, I have used [Sartorius](http://www.sartorius.com/en/products/bioprocess/air-gas-filters/) in the past, but I don't have any particular brand loyalty to them.

Let me know if you need any more help.